# SignalR not sending web requests on start

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, signalr

So, We are implementing some messaging system with signalR.
We included signalR through the latest version of Nuget. 
The application is hosted on IIS 7. We have disabled all the URL Rewrite rules.

We are using a hub, see the following code:

```
    [HubName("messages")]
    public class Messages : Hub
    {
        public void Send(string message)
        {
            Clients.showPopUp(message);
        }
    }
```

The include files in the view:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>       
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.signalR.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/signalr/hubs")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Messages/Messages.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Content of Messages.js:

```
$(function () {
    var messages = $.connection.messages;

    messages.showPopUp = function (message) {
        console.log("test");
    };

    $.connection.hub.start(function () {
        console.log('connected');
    });
});
```

Called when a message is submitted:

```
$.connection.messages.send($('#Body').val());
```

So what we get: no errors in Google Chrome console, no xhr request what so over for signal.

We have checked if the `/signalr/hubs` exists and it does, also `/signalr/negotiate` returns the following json:

```
{"Url":"/agenda/signalr","ConnectionId":"a4215b26-32f1-4a52-bf6d-4de096298a07","TryWebSockets":false,"WebSocketServerUrl":null,"ProtocolVersion":"1.0"}
```

When we call send we get the following in the console:

> Uncaught SignalR: Connection must be started before data can be sent. Call .start() before .send()

**If we debug signalR, we see start was called, but we don't hit the error or success of the jQuery ajax call and there are no xhtml requests what so ever. What are we doing wrong?**

[image: No Web requests]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try checking out this issue: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/328

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

In jquery.signalR.js change all the

```
$.ajax(url, {options});
```

to

```
$.ajax({ url: url, other options...});
```